# How to Update Folders in a Project Using Git

Tags: git

In my webapp project I use an external JavaScript project containing hundreds of files
Now I want to update the code in this external project. Luckily I only need to copy the new code/files to my project.

My first question is how would you go doing this?

My solution right now is to delete the folder for the external project, copy the new code to the same place.

Second question: Will the solution I described above mess with the VCS(Git) history for files that are copied into my project again?

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Git tracks snapshots of your working directory, not the explicit history of individual files. It does not care how you got your working directory into a particular state, only what it looks like at the time you commit.

Your solution will work just fine.